# How to support logged in custom views while still supporting static pages for anonymous users?

Tags: next.js

I have a website that is mostly for anonymous users to access public information on listings pages. A small subset of our user base will have password protected accounts that let them customize the filtering and sorting of information on these pages. The idea is that is that once the user logs in, the site can remember their viewing preferences so when they go to a particular listing it shows up the way they want it to.

Currently we are using Next.JS's Incremental Static Regeneration to serve pre-rendered pages. This is working great for anonymous users.

But I worry that if we add authentication and custom sorting, we would either have one of two issues:

1. If we keep getStaticProps, logged in users would get a flash of unstyled content as the hydrated page detects that the user is logged in and re-sorts the page content. Or they would get a [loading state](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-statically-generated-pages) before actually seeing the content.
2. If we switch to SSR, we'd get slow authentication checks on the backend for everyone on every page load including for anonymous users, who are the vast majority of our users.

Is there a better way to deal with this? I wonder if, for example, there is a tweak I can add to server.js or something that switches from static to SSR if it sees a session cookie in the request headers.

Comment: Have you considered using Next.js [Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to detect whether the user is logged in or not, and redirect/rewrite to the appropriate page for each case?

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks for the tip. I will have to switch the site's authentication system over to using cookies so it will take a while before I can confirm 100% that this works, but a simplified proof of concept I wrote using middleware has worked great so far.